# Refer to line triggered by when clause in Pyspark Databricks

Tags: dataframe, recursion, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to implement a recursive function in Databricks to fill the weight column of a Dataframe composed of articles.

This is the columns of my Dataframe
no_cpose, no_cposant, typ_art, qte_struct, pds_unit

typ_art

- can be a "P" pieces, if so the pds_unit has a value
- can be a "K" kit, is set to 0 or null > This is the value i'm trying to calculate

The weight of kit is the sum of the articles in it times the qut_struct (quantities)
but a kit can be composed of kits without any depth restriction

no_cpose is the id a the parent kit which is an article as well and no_cposant is the id of the articles inside this kit. As the kit can be composed by kits, all ids of kits can be founds in the two ids columns no_cpose and no_cposant

i've try this code but i'm facing some difficulties

```
def calculate_kit_weight(df):
    df.withColumn("pds_unit",
                when(
                    (F.col("typ_art") == "K") & ((F.col("pds_unit") == 0) | (F.col("pds_unit").isNull())),
                    calculate_kit_weight(
**                        spark.sql(f"SELECT no_cpose, no_cposant, typ_art, qte_struct, pds_unit \
                                    from table_art
                                    where no_cpose = {F.col('no_cposant')}")
                        )**
                ).otherwise(df.agg(F.sum("pds_unit")))))
calculate_kit_weight(main_df)
```

The bold part is where something wrong happen
I've also tried something like this

`**main_df.filter(F.col("no_cposant") == F.col("no_cpose"))**`

But obviously it's only returning the line where kit refer itself, which don't happen normally
So here come my question: i'm trying here to refer to each line where the when clause is triggered and return sur recursive function a subquery as if
x, the no_cposant id is K and equal 0 i want to sub query the initial dataframe (not the one passed) with the filter no_cpose equal to x. How to i refer here to the line implied by the when clause ?